# how to check if a particular user is a owner of certain directories and if not then assign this user as a owner using bash script

Tags: macos, bash

I am new in linux and currently have to perform a task where I have to check if a particular user is an owner of a directory and its subdirectory and if not then assign him as a owner. I need to do this in a bash script so anyone if can provide me a sample would be really great.

**Scenario:**
path = "/opt/dev/myapp"

this directory contains more subdirectories and the files

Need to check if the user "devuser" is an owner or not and if not then assign him as an owner.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 4):

You could just assign the user to that directory, regardless the fact that before doing the check it was or wasn't:

```
chown -R bob bobs-directory
```

where `-R` means go recursively down the directory tree, `bob` is the name of the user and `bobs-directory` is the root directory you want to give ownership to.

Answer (score 3):

As [Alberto Zaccagni](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17522099/1630171) correctly said, you could just change the owner right away. If you want to check anyway, you can do it like this:

```
dir="/opt/dev/myapp"
username=devuser

[ "$(stat -c "%U" "$dir")" == "$username" ] || chown -R $username "$dir"
```

`stat` is a utility for displaying information about files (owner, permissions, times, …).

Please note that you must not put whitespace around the `=` when assigning variables. Also, I'd recommend against using a variable name like `path` as that's easily confused with the environment variable `$PATH`.

**Edit:** Mac OS X ships BSD `stat`, which has different options, so you have to change the command like this:

```
[ "$(stat -f "%Su" "$dir")" == "$username" ] || chown -R $username "$dir"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! 
I just checked running it and it works but still I got below messages in console:</br>



<blink>
stat: illegal option -- c
usage: stat [-FlLnqrsx] [-f format] [-t timefmt] [file ...]
[: : integer expression expected

Also could you explain a little about this command ?
</blink>

Comment: So you're running OSX, not Linux. You should have tagged your question accordingly then. See updated answer.